# htaccess rewrite loop?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have user-uploaded files stored in

```
/public/upload/*
```

for instance:

```
/public/upload/gallery/segway/child-on-a-segway.jpg
```

My current .htaccess rules already eliminate the `/public` part, but I still need to get rid of the `/upload` part, BUT, only for files with a given extension and not contained in one other directories, such as `js` or `img`. My current .htaccess looks like this (typical for Zend Framework projects):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

In hopes of getting rid of the `/upload` part working, I wrote this at the end of my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?<!upload|img|js|less|css)/.*(jpg|mp3|png)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /upload/$1
```

Basically, if a file has jpg, png or mp3 extension and the path to it does NOT start with "upload", "js", "css", "img" or "less", prepend "upload" to the request URI. Well, it fails. When I type in the address bar: `http://example.com/gallery/1/php193A.jpg`, I get a 303 error:

> You don't have permission to access /upload//public/upload/public/upload/public/upload/public/upload/public/upload/public/upload/public/upload/public/upload/public/gallery/1/php193A.jpg/1/php193A.jpg/gallery/1/php193A.jpg/1/php193A.jpg/upload/public/gallery/1/php193A.jpg/1/php193A.jpg/gallery/1/php193A.jpg/1/php193A.jpg/upload/public/upload/public/gallery/1/php193A.jpg/1/php193A.jpg/gallery/1/php193A.jpg/1/php193A.jpg/upload/public/gallery/1/php193A.jpg/1/php193A.jpg/gallery/1/php193A.jpg/1/php193A.jpg...

And the URL goes on and on for several dozen lines, as if it was looped.

This is the first time I'm dealing with .htaccess rewrite rules. I'd appreciate some help in setting them straight, as I'm completely lost here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I actually laughed pretty hard at the error message, ahaha

Comment: My client won't find it too amusing though :(

Comment: Which is why I'm currently trying to debug it for you lol

Comment: Hmm...in this part: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?<!upload|img|js|less|css)/.*(jpg|mp3|png)` what does the `<` do?

Comment: It's a lookback. I'm not 100% sure it's the proper way to use it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you *"wrote this at the end of my .htaccess"*. TBH I see no way how that rule should be reached (**order of rules matters**) without changing some other rules a bit (like, removing `L` flag).

Let's examine this request: `/gallery/segway/child-on-a-segway.jpg`.

1. It will be rewritten to `/public/gallery/segway/child-on-a-segway.jpg` by this rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1`
2. Because there is no such file, it will be further rewritten to `/public/index.php` by this rule: `RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]`. Because of `[L]` flag rewrite goes to next iteration.
3. On 2nd rewrite iteration this rule `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]` sees that  `/public/index.php` does exists and terminates any further rewrites.

---

Considering all of the above it become obvious that such additional rule needs to be placed somewhere in the middle without modifying any of the existing rules. This is the rule I come up with that matches your requirements (based on your attempt to rewrite):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public|img|js|css)/.*$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/upload%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(jpg|png|mp3))$ /public/upload%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```

The correct place to place it, in my opinion, would be before this rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1`. Such .htaccess will have the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public|img|js|css)/.*$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/upload%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(jpg|png|mp3))$ /public/upload%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

I have tested it -- it works. It may not be the most optimal as file lookup is executed (`-f`), but considering it will only work for a limited number of extensions (this is a good requirement) it should be fine (if it would be for EVERY extension then it will slowdown system on busy server/under load).

**P.S.**
As I understand, the `(?<` pattern means "variable length look-behind" (although I'm not 100% sure on this).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! It works like a charm, and I doubt I'd ever come up with this myself. You literally saved my butt ;) The number o extensions may become greater if the client requests, e.g., .flv files upload as well, but it will still be a limited set. Thanks again.